# Why the performance difference in += vs +?

Tags: raku

Debugging some code ended up testing the differences in the statements such as `$counter=$counter + 1;` vs `$counter+=1;`

```
my $run=True;
my $counter=0;
my $sup=Supply.interval(1);
my $tap= $sup.tap({
    $run=$_ < 10;
});
{
    while $run {
        #$counter+=1;
        $counter=$counter + 1;
    }
    $tap.close;
    say "Iterations per second: {$counter/(now - ENTER now)}"; #
}
```

I'm getting around 20% more iterations per second for `$counter=$counter+1` compared to  `$counter+=1;`

Whats happening in the background thats so different?

**EDIT:**

Interestingly when trying this with an array and hyper operators the performance is greatly  *increased* when using the `+=`.

eg
`@counter=@counter>>+<<@value;`
vs
`@counter>>+=<<@value;`
I get about 2.8 times the iterations of the loop using `>>+=<<` with arrays of 10_000 elements.

As far as I can tell via the `time` cmd there is minimal parallel execution in either case (total user + system is within 2% of real time).

Any insight on how/why this is would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've golfed your benchmark to:

```
my $a = 0; for ^10_000_000 { $a += 1 }
```

vs:

```
my $a = 0; for ^10_000_000 { $a = $a + 1 }
```

If you run these examples in the profiler with `perl6 --profile -e '...'`, then you'll see that the difference is indeed in the 20% range.  The only thing that is really different, is the total number of frames: 49935579 for `+= 1`, and 39932197 for `= $a + 1`.

The underlying difference (before any optimizations), is that `+=` goes through a metaop path.  It is not defined as a separate operator, so it needs to create the operator on the fly, taking the original operator (`&infix:<+>`) as a parameter and building a `Callable` out of that.

FWIW, I'm glad to see the difference is only 20% nowadays: it wasn't too long ago when anything involving metaops was at least 2x as slow  :-)

Comment: Interesting. I decided to run this on my machine and added the `$a++` variation which did worse than the other two.